# jQuery store div parent id , and delete it from an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to build input element dynamically with option to add and remove the inputs.
also I have drop down that build dynamically from my data base using php.
while I am adding input I sore the parent id in array and when I am delete the input I am using splice to delete it. every box I am adding or remove contain several inputs

I adding the inputs successfully also to the array and succeed to pass them using ajax, the issue is when I am deleting 1 input it deleting all my parents divs like in loop.

```
   var x = 1
var appleTestList;
var appleinputList = new Array();

$('#applePlus').click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            var wrapper         = $("#appleDinamicBox"); //Fields wrapper
            ; //initlal text box count 
            $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "sqlFunctrions.php",
            data: 'func=dropDownbyValue&table=test&value=Test_ID&display=Test_Name&column=Test_Type&valueBy=Apple&selectName=appleTest&chooseFrom=Test',
            success: function(msg){
                appleTestList=msg;
            }

        }); // Ajax Call

            var htmlString='';

                x++; //text box increment
                htmlString=htmlString + '<div class="seperate" id="'+x+'"><div class="col-lg-5"><label>Test Name:</label>'; 
                htmlString = htmlString + '<select name="appleTestName'+x+'" id="appleTestName'+x+'" class="form-control"><option value=\"0\">Test</option>' +appleTestList+'</select>';
                htmlString = htmlString + '</div><div class="col-lg-5"><label>Namber Of Setups</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="appleNumOfSetups'+x+'" id="appleNumOfSetups'+x+'"></div><img src="images/minus-s.png" id="appleMinus" class="remove_field"></div>';
                $(wrapper).append(htmlString); //add input box            

                appleinputList.push(x);

                $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    alert(id);
    appleinputList.splice(appleinputList.indexOf(parseInt(id)),1);

            alert(id);

});

}
```

can you my mistake, there is any other way to do that?

thanks,
Cfir.

Comment: Possibly this line: $(this).parent('div').remove();

Comment: I would add a `data-targetid=x` to the `.remove_field` element and pull it out explicitly (`id=$(this).data('targetid')`) in the handler instead of using parent relationships.

Comment: Have you considered using a template library like Knockout to build dynamic views? It's worth checking out: http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you bind new `$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field"` handler every time you clicked on `#applePlus` (which results in multiple handler calls). Move this code out of `#applePlus` click handler.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvpnxqoh/).

```
$('#applePlus').click(function()
{
    var wrapper = $("#appleDinamicBox"); //Fields wrapper

    ...

    appleinputList.push(x);
});

$("#appleDinamicBox").on("click", ".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    appleinputList.splice(appleinputList.indexOf(parseInt(id)),1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the answer :)